# Elasticsearch too many running threads

Tags: java, elasticsearch, cpu, cpu-usage

We have a big problem with our ES cluster. One of our nodes is always on 99% CPU. For some reason it has about 3 times more threads running for the `elasticsearch` process compared to normal node. I have attached 2 `htop` screenshots for 2 nodes, one overloaded and another normal. Please advise!

Thank you!

Overloaded Node
[image: overloaded node]

Normal Node
[image: normal node]

**UPDATE**

1. Cluster architecture:

   11 nodes, 2 dedicated masters, 9 data nodes.
2. Nodes Hardware Properties

   Masters:

   - CPU: 8x Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-1620 v2 @ 3.70GHz
   - Memory: 32GB
   - Disk: 120GB

   Slaves:

   1. CPU: 12x Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-1650 v2 @ 3.50GHz
   2. Memory: 64GB
   3. Disk: 2.7T
3. Documents in cluster:

   ~200 Millions
4. Index conf:

   Each index is split in 10 shards (5 primary, 5 replica)
5. Queries:

   Search RT: `~ 250/s`, Index RT: `~ 6K/s`
6. OS

   `Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS`
7. JAVA

> ```
> java version "1.7.0_60"
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_60-b19)
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.60-b09, mixed mode)
> ```

Comment: I'm afraid your screen shots by themselves are not very helpful. I'd add the following: number of nodes in the cluster, memory, cpu and disk for each node, number of documents in the cluster, overall cluster and index configurations, mappings, query volume, insert volume, output from ES diagnostics like node stats, operating system, jvm version.

Comment: @JohnPetrone I have posted an update with the required information. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out.

`[2014-07-07 13:38:42,521][DEBUG][index.search.slowlog.query] [n013.my_cluster] [my_index][3] took[2s], took_millis[2066], types[my_type], stats[], search_type[QUERY_THEN_FETCH], total_shards[5], source[{"size":20,"from":0,"sort":{"_score":"desc"},"query":{"filtered":{"query":{"query_string":{"query":"my eight words space separated query","fields":["description","tags"],"default_operator":"OR"}},"filter":{"and":[{"range":{"ats":{"lte":1404730800}}},{"terms":{"aid":[1,2,4]}}]},"_cache":false}}}], extra_source[]`

The problem resided inside `"filter": {"and": ...}`, looks like these kind of queries are heavier for ES compared to `bool` type queries. So whenever you want to apply some `filters`, please use `bool` filters (`must`, `must_not` and `should`)

Reff: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-filter.html

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the sparse info at hand, I have a couple of guesses that could potentially be the problem:

- Shards are not well balanced and you are having hot spotting. Ensure that your most heavily used indexes are sharded in such a way that each machine can do its share of work. Also, look into the index level "index.routing.allocation.total_shards_per_node" to try to force an equal balance.
- Perhaps on the search side, you are specifying that the search should always go to the "primary" shard. The primary designation isn't something that balances, so basically, the first node up has the primary shard and the others that come up after are all secondaries.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. We did have a hot spot situation regarding that we had 9 data nodes with `10 shards` for each index so there always was a node that would take 2 shards. For testing purposes we've changed our secondary master to be data node as well and migrated reallocated the shards - unfortunately no change.

About the search requests, we have the default configuration, so it's querying replicas.

Comment: Try setting: "index.routing.allocation.total_shards_per_node" to 1 for each index which should force an equal balance assumming 10 datanodes and 10 shards (including replicas) per index. Note: THIS SHOULD ONLY BE DONE FOR TESTING. Longer term, you're likely better off with more shards per index which will give your total_shards_per_node some flexibility.